# While loop failing to begin ignoring if statements and conditions as a result

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm working on a program that is a guessing game. However the loop for identifying whether an individual guessed the correct number fails to even begin I get this:

```
Player 1: Type a number between 0 and 99 and press return:
1
Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return:
1
Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.
```

The loop terminates before it even begins and I can't figure out how to make it work.

This is the code for the loop:

```
  printf( "Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return: \n");
  scanf("%d",&guesses);

  while (remainingguesses != 0) {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);

    if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
      printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");
      remainingguesses = guesses - 1;
    }

    else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber){
        printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");
        remainingguesses = guesses - 1;
    }

    else{
          printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
    }
  }

  if (remainingguesses == 0)
    printf("Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.\n");
```

I'm fairly new to programming so excuse me for my ignorance.

**Here's the full code if you'd like to see that:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int secretnumber;
  int guesses;
  int secretnumberguess;
  int remainingguesses;

  while (1)  {
    printf("Player 1: Type a number between 0 and 99 and press return:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumber);

    if (secretnumber > 99 || secretnumber < 0) {
      printf("Secret number cannot be greater than 99 or below 0.\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  printf( "Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return: \n");
  scanf("%d",&guesses);

  while (remainingguesses != 0) {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);

    if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
      printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");
      remainingguesses = guesses - 1;
    }

    else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber){
        printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");
        remainingguesses = guesses - 1;
    }

    else{
          printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
    }
  }

  if (remainingguesses == 0)
    printf("Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is remainingguesses set to 0 initially?

Comment: No remainingguesses is the outcome of guesses - 1. It has no value i set it to.

Comment: After scanf("%d",&guesses); add this line printf("%i", remainingguesses );. What value is printed?

Comment: int remainingguesses; has no value set initially, hence it will not enter the while loop. It needs an initial value.

Comment: @cosmoonot more specifically, `remainingguesses` can have any random value, but it'll most likely be zero.

Comment: You should turn on your compiler warnings, read them, and *fix* them. Doing that will point you to the same cause as given by cosmoonot, but then you only require the compiler, not the StackOverflow community.

Comment: Sure, it could be any random value, I understand, but he is not setting any value initially, hence it skips the while loop and goes straight to the if statement below.

Comment: Got that to work but now I have a different problem involving the: printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",remainingguesses);

Comment: Haha! Part of coding, @CoffeeMug. Baby steps, look at the compiler errors.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us know, if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your remainingguesses is causing you to not enter the loop. Perhaps instead of using that as a check use a flag and inside the loop check for remaining guesses in an if loop. And inside the if loop change the flag accordingly.