# Loop terminates because of condition, but the condition is necessary?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm working on a program that is a guessing game.

The problem is I have to set `remainingguesses` to 0 so that the amount of guesses a person can make decreases by 1. But at the same time the condition set in the loop is based on the `remainingguesses` not being 0. Meaning once it is 0 the loop terminates and moves on.

I don't know how to solve this while making the condition in the loop work properly.

**Here's the loop in question:**

```
 printf( "Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return: \n");
  scanf("%d",&guesses);

  remainingguesses = 0;

  while (remainingguesses != 0) {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);
    remainingguesses = guesses - 1;

    if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
      printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");
    }

    else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber){
      printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");
    }

    else{
          printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
    }
  }

  if (remainingguesses == 0)
    printf("Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.\n");
```

**Here's the full code in question if needed:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int secretnumber;
  int guesses;
  int secretnumberguess;
  int remainingguesses;

  while (1)  {
    printf("Player 1: Type a number between 0 and 99 and press return:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumber);

    if (secretnumber > 99 || secretnumber < 0) {
      printf("Secret number cannot be greater than 99 or below 0.\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  printf( "Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return: \n");
  scanf("%d",&guesses);

  remainingguesses = 0;

  while (remainingguesses != 0) {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",remainingguesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);
    remainingguesses = guesses - 1;

    if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
      printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");
    }

    else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber){
      printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");
    }

    else{
          printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
    }
  }

  if (remainingguesses == 0)
    printf("Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.\n");

  return 0;
```

Comment: You have `remainingguesses = guesses - 1;` but you don't change `guesses` in the loop, so the number of guesses remaining does not vary.  You probably need `remainingguesses--;` or equivalent.  In fact, I'd probably do it differently; I'd probably count the number of guesses taken: `int num_guesses; for (num_guesses = 0; num_guesses < guesses; num_guesses++) { …loop… }` and then check whether they took too many guesses after the loop (remembering to break the loop if they get the answer right).

Comment: This is closely related to [`while` loop failing to begin — ignoring if statement and conditions as a result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244415/while-loop-failing-to-begin-ignoring-if-statements-and-conditions-as-a-result); same author, same basic program.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by remainingguesses--; do you mean subtract it with some variable or literally that.

Comment: I assumed you were learning C and would be aware of the operators in C.  The `--` (double-minus) operators are called the decrement operators, and the `++` (double-plus) operators are called the increment operators.  They subtract or add one (or, for pointers, the size of one object — but presumably pointers are still in the future for you).  There's a pre-increment form `++a` (increments `a` and returns the incremented value) and a post-decrement form `a--` (returns the original value of `a` but decrements the variable).  Further details are in your text book.  Please consult that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int secretnumber;
  int guesses;
  int secretnumberguess;
  int flag=0;

  while (1)  {
    printf("Player 1: Type a number between 0 and 99 and press return:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumber);

    if (secretnumber > 99 || secretnumber < 0) {
      printf("Secret number cannot be greater than 99 or below 0.\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  printf( "Type the number of guesses that player 2 gets and press return: \n");
  scanf("%d",&guesses);


  while (guesses > 0 && flag==0) {
    printf("Player 2: Type your guess and press return (guesses remaining:%d):\n",guesses);
    scanf(" %d",&secretnumberguess);
    guesses=guesses - 1;

    if (secretnumberguess > secretnumber) {
      printf("Your guess was greater than the secret number.\n");
    }

    else if (secretnumberguess < secretnumber){
      printf("Your guess was less than the secret number.\n");
    }

    else{
          printf("Your guess was equal to the secret number. You win!\n");
          flag=1;
    }
  }

  if (guesses == 0 && flag==0)
    printf("Sorry you are out of guesses. You lose.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got an enormous error just compiling this.,#include <stdio.h>

hw05.c:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from hw05.c:15:
/usr/include/libio.h:332: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘size_t’'

Comment: That's all of it

Comment: aren't you using gcc compiler?

Comment: im editing in emacs, and compiling in putty using gcc compiler

Comment: can u try compiling with gcc in your terminal? The code works fine for me

Comment: Which is your os?

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I had some text before the stdio statement  and the gcc obviously couldn't compile properly because of it. I'm very sorry for the trouble and Thank you so much! It works like a charm now!

Comment: (palm on face) yeah. Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably a simple way of coding this.

```
read guesses;

while (guesses > 0) {
  read input;
  if (input == secret) {
    print "you win!!";
    return;
  }
  else {
    print "try again!";
  }
  guesses--;
}

print "Sorry! You are out of guesses";
```